# ParseRequestException: object not found for update

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am implementing Parse Push Notifications and am getting the following error on saving my custom object for push notification targeting.

Here is how I initialize parse in my `OnCreate` method of `Application` class

```
Parse.initialize(context, PushNotificationManager.PN_APPLICATION_ID_PROD, PushNotificationManager.PN_CLIENT_KEY_PROD);
final ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                 if(e != null)
                installation.saveEventually();
            }
         });
```

Later in my code, I save/update some objects:

```
final ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        installation.put(KEY_SOME_KEY, true);
        installation.put(KEY_ANOTHER_KEY, some_string);
        installation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if(e != null)
                    installation.saveEventually();
            }
        });
```

on calling `saveInBackground()` , I get the following error and my objects are not updated:

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: object not found for update
com.parse.ParseRequest.newPermanentException(ParseRequest.java:391)
com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponse(ParseRESTCommand.java:197)
com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:258)
com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:254)
bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:702)
bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:690)
bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

What could be going wrong ??

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because Parse notices that the local ParseInstallation object is changed and in the next call to saveInBackground(), just sends the "dirty" columns, But the object was not already on the server, hence this error.

What worked for me is this :

```
final ParseInstallation pi = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
pi.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        // Once the object is already saved, update it and save it again
        if (e == null) {
            pi.put("KEY1", "value1");
            pi.put("KEY1", "value1");
            pi.saveInBackground();
        } else {
            Log.d (TAG,"Failed to save parseInstallation");
            Log.d (TAG, "Printing stacktrace ...");
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize parse in the following manner and not as shown in the official documentation (v1.7)

```
// Enable Local Datastore.
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

// Add your initialization code here
Parse.initialize(this, "*******", "******");

ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

// save the installation
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```